Within a single excel cell, checking if values from a range are found in another range and equal a value found in another range
I have a list of available codes that people can choose from (A2:A21), some of which are required and some of which are optional when they submit their selection of choices (flagged as "Y" or "N" B2:B21).
I would like to be able to have a flag in D2 to say whether the choices they have made (D5:D16) contain all the required codes ("Y" values in B2:21). Any number of optional modules ("N" values in B2:B21) is permitted.
I feel like this need an array as I get a #SPILL error otherwise but I'm currently getting a zero in D2 if I try an array.


Post some sample data using Markdown Table, insert a desired result table and show us your attempts.

Put a SUM() function infront of COUNTIFS() function.

SPILL error means your spill-aray doesn't have enough space to spill (drop down). slide it one cell over and it should work. And like Harun24hr said, put it inside SUM() and you'll get a total result.

@Harun24hr amazing thanks - this seems to have done the trick and now gives me an 8 in D2. In case it helps anyone else, this is the function I had: {=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,$D$5:$D$16,$B$2:$B$21,"Y"))}

@GrumblyMun I assume you do not need array entry. Just put =SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A21,D5:D16,B2:B21,"Y")).

@Harun24hr Thanks - you're right, no array needed.

@Excellor How to simulate data: 1) for Code, enter the first two and fill down; 2) for Required, use [B2]=MAKEARRAY(numberOfRows;1;LAMBDA(r;c;IF(RAND()<0,5;"Y";"N"))), then copy and paste values.

@rotabor Thanks for the info! I asked for a data sample before OP included any, so no clue what to start with.

@Excellor Thanks for your reply and apologies for not including data initially - I tried to embed the screenshot but didn't manage it. Literally my first post so still figuring things out!

@GrumblyMun no problem! You can just (copy-)paste it in and the editor will format it for you. If you still fail and only get the link in, someone will probably edit the format so it's fixed. We're here to help.

You don't need to enter your formula as an array formula. As noted above, the #SPILL error means that the formula doesn't have enough space to expand downward. If you move the formula next to your "Choices" column, it will expand down as required.
Column E contains a standard spill formula: =COUNTIFS(A2:A21,D5:D16,B2:B21,"Y"), and column F contains the array-formula version of it. You should try it yourself—while they produce the same output, they behave differently when you interact with them.
To get the count of how many of the required choices have been made, you can wrap your formula in SUM:
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A21,D5:D16,B2:B21,"Y"))



I can propose you the next solution:

=AND(INDEX(B2:B16,XMATCH(D5:D7,A2#))="Y")

Consider reference appropriate ranges:
=AND(INDEX(Required,XMATCH(Choices,Code))="Y")

